# SSAS MDX Calculated Measure Based on Related Dimension Attribute Value

Tags: ssas, mdx

I have a measure `[Measures].[myMeasure]` that I would like to create several derivatives of based on the related attribute values.
e.g. if the related `[Location].[City].[City].Value = "Austin"` then I want the new calculated measure to return the value of `[Measures].[myMeasure]`,   otherwise, I want the new calculated measure to return 0.

Also, I need the measure to aggregate correctly meaning sum all of the leaf level values to create a total.

The below works at the leaf level or as long as the current member is set to Austin...

```
Create Member CurrentCube.[Measures].[NewMeasure] as
iif(
[Location].[City].currentmember = [Location].[City].&[Austin], 
[Measures].[myMeasure], 
0
);
```

This has 2 problems.
1 - I don't always have `[Location].[City]` in context.
2. When multiple cities are selected this return 0.

I'm looking for a solution that would work regardless of whether the related dimension is in context and will roll up by summing the atomic values based on a formula similar to above.

To add more context consider a transaction table with an amount field.  I want to convert that amount into measures such as payments, deposits, return, etc... based on the related account.

Comment: Let's say myMeasure returns a value of 1 for both locations in Austin, what is the Austin aggregated total? 1 or 2?

Comment: in `CurrentCube.[Measures].[NewMeasure]` you should use `IS` rather than `=` when comparing to a member

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the answer but just a couple of general helpers:

1 You should use `IS` rather than `=` when comparing to a member
2 You should use `null` rather than `0` - 0/NULL are effecitvely the same but using `0` will slow things up **a lot** as the calculation will be fired many more times. (this might help with the second section of your question)

```
Create Member CurrentCube.[Measures].[NewMeasure] as
iif(
[Location].[City].currentmember IS [Location].[City].&[Austin], 
[Measures].[myMeasure], 
NULL
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the input.  I ended up creating the measure in the query that the dsv is using.  There probably is a better way to handle this, but this time I pushed the burden to process time.

Comment: no no Paul- you've done the right thing: although possible in `mdx` you're better pushing this task up the data pipeline. Hopefully you read my advise as it is relevant for writing `mdx` in general.

Comment: Thanks, whytheq.  I appreciate the response and I want ahead and ran a test using your input.  Worked well.